# I don't understand the code, Tic Tac Toe game by michael dawson

Tags: python

there's some part of the code that I don't really understand, can someone explain it to me

```
def winner(board):
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                   (3, 4, 5),
                   (6, 7, 8),
                   (0, 3, 6),
                   (1, 4, 7),
                   (2, 5, 8),
                   (0, 4, 8),
                   (2, 4, 6))

    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner

        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE

        return None
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble understanding?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: if board[row[[0] == board[row[1] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:

Comment: @JohnCruz Added a bit on to my answer to specifically address the `if` statement. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: #CrazyCasta the winner = board[row[0]], I'm a little confused about it. will you explain it to me? It would mean a lot to me.. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way of checking to see if the board state is a win state. The board is arranged with the following indices:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

So the tuple in ways to win of (0, 1, 2) checks if the first row is all the same. The (0, 3, 6) tuple checks if the first column is all the same. Finally, the (0, 4, 8) checks the down and to the right diagonal. It does this with the if statement you asked about:

```
if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
```

For example with the (0, 3, 6) row it looks at board index 0, compares that with board index 3 and board index 6, if they're all equal to each other and not equal to EMPTY then that's a win condition for whichever player has filled in those squares.

Empty is presumably the token for saying neither player has put a token in that square, so:

```
if EMPTY not in board:
    return TIE
```

basically says, if the board is full and no one was a winner, then it was a tie.

Comment: Ok, I understand the if statement, thanks, now the winner = board[row[0]], I'm still confused with that one.

Comment: So each board position can either contain "EMPTY" or one of the two players' tokens. In the case that three in a row are occupied by a player, the player who's token occupies those spaces is the winner. `board[row[0]]` is just getting who's token is in the first space.